# Setting new hostname on CentOS, it changes back after restart

Tags: centos, hostname, host

On CentOS (5.x) I have a VPS that has hostname set to "olddomain.com", at least this is the domain I am getting when typing "hostname" command.

I want to change it to 'localhost.localdomain' because I think it is more generic and reliable.

localhost.localdomain already exists in these files: /etc/sysconfig/network AND /etc/hosts

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
GATEWAY=95.xx.xx.xx
```

AND

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

So next I tried these commands:

```
hostname localhost.localdomain
```

AND

```
hostname -v localhost.localdomain
```

"hostname" command now returns this new value. But after restart it changes back to olddomain.com or at least this is the "hostname" command returns.

Anything else to edit?

Comment: Did you changed the /etc/hostname too ?

Comment: Is NetworkManager enabled? If so, NM will sometimes interfere with your manual configuration. Do a `chkconfig NetworkManager --list` to see if it is enabled.

Comment: It says: NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

Comment: @spud you mean /etc/hosts file? I did not edit it because it already contains "localhost.localdomain" there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following lines into your  `/etc/sysctl.conf` configuration file.

```
kernel.hostname = hostname
kernel.domainname = domain.com
```

And execute the command `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` to read and apply the changes of your `/etc/sysctl.conf` configuration file.

Comment: Would this be correct? kernel.hostname = localhost; kernel.domainname = localhost.localdomain

Comment: Not really. First, the semi-colon is not required. Second, each parameter should be on its own line. Third, it doesn't make sense for having a FQHN of "localhost.localhost.localdomain".

Comment: Or, delete the lines that are there in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` that are preventing your hostname assignment from surviving a reboot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you edit the /etc/sysconfig/network file?  Or are you just showing it's contents?  The hostname command does not actually edit these files.  When the system starts the init scripts read the host name from the configuration files and this setting is then passed to the hostname command.  In additoion as mentioned by other posts be sure to edit your hosts file so that the mapping for your hostname <-> ip is correct on the local host.

More information is available in the [Red Hat documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-networkscripts.html)

Also are you using Network Manager to manage your network interfaces?  If so you will need to go into NM and make sure the settings jive there as well.

Comment: I was not using network manager. I was able to solve this after editing the two config files to a different value then rebooted, then changed back to localhost.localdomain and it remained like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't edit the files `/etc/sysconfig/network` and  `/etc/hosts` because these **already contained** the hostname I wanted (localhost.localdomain), so just by command `hostname localhost.localdomain` it didn't remain saved after reboot.

**But** then my host edited these two files to a different host name, rebooted the server (without any other command, just editing) and the new hostname applied and remained changed. Then I edited files again and set them to localhost.localdomain as they are on some other of my VPS and now they updated and remained to localhost as I wanted.

**Edit (11 years later):** while working on an older OS (CentOS 7.x) I was unable to change hostname by any method, the only thing that eventually worked was @bintut's answer below, editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding:

```
kernel.hostname = hostname
kernel.domainname = domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `/etc/sysconfig/network` is deprecated. Try `/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/hosts` and `/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/network`.

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/hosts is same as above hosts (no old_domain in it), and the second one doesn't exist: /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/network

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/network` is not deprecated. This is the correct place to put some settings. See http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-networkscripts.html